# Infragistics XamDataGrid special grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

How can I set field layout to XamDataGrid like this:
[image: expected layout]

Any ideas are welcome, either by grouping or using master-detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the grid by the Consumer field.  To get the headers on top only, set [HeaderPlacementInGroupBy](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WPF/2013.2/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.FieldLayoutSettings~HeaderPlacementInGroupBy.html) to OnTopOnly on the FieldLayoutSettings:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
<igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" HeaderPlacementInGroupBy="OnTopOnly"/>
```

Comment: That link is broken. Though thank you for HeaderPlacementInGroupBy. =)

Comment: I have updated the link and made the property name in the text the link so the post is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The grid should look this way if you drag the 'Consumer' field into the group by area. Is this what what you mean?

Comment: Nope. If we place this field in a group area, table header will appear in every group. And we want it appear once on top of overall table.